# question on Armory bitcoin wallet scripting

Tags: armory, python

Has anyone built the Armory Bitcoin wallet successfully and created the wallet using python and Armory as a library instead of using the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this page on the Armory website](https://bitcoinarmory.com/using-armory-python/)? It describes how to do what it is you appear to be asking to do.

First you import everything from armoryengine.ALL.

You have `PyBtcWallet().readWalletFile(filename)` to get a wallet object. Then you can do things with the wallet object.

You can also use TheBDM (Block Data Manager) to register callbacks for certain signals, such as new blocks.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, yeah I did see it, but where do I get the filename because on the Armory website the readWalletFile method takes CLI_ARGS[0] as a parameter and throws  an IndexError

Comment: It is a file ending in .wallet. On Windows, it will be in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Armory`. On Linux, it will be in `/home/<user>/.armory`. I don't know about OS X.

Comment: oh no, the title in the Armory wallet says, Accessing A Wallet and I want to create a wallet. I just built from source code, hence I want to create a wallet.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.